# Doubt regarding proof that a convergent sequence cannot have two different limits

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

The proof regarding the fact that convergent sequences cannot have two different limits is given as follows in Vladimir A Zorich's Mathematical Analysis 1, page 82.

> Let $\lim_{n\to\infty} \ \  x_n = A_1$  and $\lim_{n\to\infty} \ \  x_n = A_2$. If $A_1 \neq A_2$ , we fix non-intersecting neighborhoods $V(A_1)$ and $V(A_2)$ of $A_1$ and $A_2$ .
> These neighborhoods might be, for example, the $δ$-neighborhoods of $A_1$
> and $A_2$ for $δ < \frac l2 |A_1 − A_2 |$. By definition of limit we find
> indices $N_1$ and $N_2$ such that $x_n ∈ V (A_1)$ for all $n > N_1$ and $x_n ∈ V (A_2 )$ for all $n > N_2$. But then for $N = \max\{N_1 , N_2\}$ we have
> $x_n ∈ V (A_1 ) ∩ V (A_2 )$. But this is impossible, since $V (A_1) ∩ V (A_2) = ∅$.

My question regarding this is, this is only for non intersecting neighborhoods, not for generic neighborhoods. How does this prove it for generic neighborhoods.

Comment: What do you mean? There are no neighborhoods in the statement of the proposition. The author picked two non intersecting neighborhoods because it was convenient in order to prove the proposition. That's all.

Comment: This proof uses that $\mathbb{R}^n$ is *Hausdorff*, which is precisely the property that one can always find two disjoint neighborhoods which separate two points.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos The proposition was only for non-intersecting neighborhoods. But for two sequences to have the same limits, shouldn't it be that all neighborhoods of the two limit points of the same $\varepsilon$ should be equal?

Comment: Again: the proposition is **not** about neighborhoods. It's about sequences and their limits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you meant $A_1 \ne A_2$.

It is general because for any $A_1$ and $A_2$, we can always choose/ construct the non-intersecting neighborhood, by choosing $\delta$ to be small enough.  $\delta < \frac12 |A_1 - A_2|$.

Comment: Hey, sorry for the error, have corrected it. I get how we can choose non intersecting neighborhoods and the proof for the same, but what about intersecting neighborhoods. How does the proof for the non-intersecting case affect the intersecting one?

Comment: @Orph  It doesn't.  The whole point of the proof that you cited is that when $A_1 \neq A_2$, you can always construct the pertinent non-intersecting neighborhoods.  The demonstration is based on that.  The proof that you cited intentionally avoids any consideration of intersecting neighborhoods as not relevant to the analysis.  It is sufficient that the pertinent non-intersecting neighborhoods can always be constructed.